# How to prevent argparse from exiting if the user specifies '-v' or '--version'

Tags: python, argparse

I want to enable my user to enter `myCLI -v` and let the program continue running instead of exiting. I know that I can disable the option with the optional argument `-h` by overriding it but I don't know how to do it with `-v`.

Here is my code:

```
import argparse

PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="myCLI", add_help=False)
PARSER.add_argument("-h", "--help", help="show this help message", action="store_true")
PARSER.add_argument("-v", "--version", action="version", version="myCLI 1.0")
```

Comment: You do the same thing. It's the `"version"` action that makes `-v` exit immediately when it is parsed.

Comment: Sure, so what action should I insert instead? @chepner

Comment: That depends on what you want your program to actually *do*. `store_true`, like you used with `-h`, seems reasonable.

Comment: With `-h` I checked if the flag is on and then used `PARSER.format_help()` but there is not such a function for the version. I want to return a string like the action version would do but just not to exit the program @chepner

Comment: Maybe `action="store_const", const="myCLI 1.0"`?

Comment: An then just to return the const value when this flag is up? Is there a "prettier" way ? @adamkwm

Comment: The only reason the `version` keyword argument is needed is to provide the `version` action a value to report. If you are just going to report the version *after* you parse the arguments, you can store it any variable you like, or just hard-code it: `if args.version: print("myCLI 1.0")`